# qgis2web cannot find QtWebKit

Tags: qgis, pyqt, qgis2web, arch-linux

I have QGIS 2.18.16, in Arch Linux; I wanted to use the qgis2web plugin and I realized it is not working anymore (it used to work last time I used it a few months back)
I get the following error

> cannot import name QtWebKit

I have QtWebkit installed - not sure why it cannot find it; 
as a side note, with the developer version qgis2web works fine (but not all needed plugins are available, so I cannot use it)

Comment: Others have come across this problem:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/523

I am not aware of any solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks, I have seen similar discussions but not an answer this is why I posted the question; I will keep looking

Comment: @TomChadwin Please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered. (You can always update the answer once it's figured out)

Answer (score 1):

Others have come across this problem:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/523

I am not aware of any solution, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the qgis2web 2.0.0 version from qgis2web plugin page

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/

and I was able to make work with QGIS 2.18.17 on Linux Mint.